# PHP flush not working on centOS with Apache

Tags: php, apache, centos, fastcgi, fpm

I have a centOS 8 server with Apache FPM/FastCGI as webserver.
I want the output to be seen right after each echo.
I tried setting `output_buffering = Off` in `php.ini` and used below code:

```
ob_implicit_flush();
ob_start();
echo '1';
ob_end_flush();
@ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(5);
echo '2';
```

but page remains on loading for 5 seconds and outputs 12 instead of outputting 1 then 2 after 5 seconds.

I used `fastcgi_finish_request()` to output the whole buffer and do stuff in background and it works correctly.

And also, gzip and deflate are both turned off.

I use above code on my local Windows machine with Apache and also on another server with LiteSpeed and they work without a problem.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you get this to work? It is really hard to find anything online for a solution on CentOs!

Comment: It's actually webserver related. Ended up writing something like this:
public function SendImmediately($Func)
    {
        if (php_sapi_name() === 'fpm-fcgi') {
            echo $Func;
            fastcgi_finish_request();
        } else {
            ob_start();
            echo $Func;
            header('Connection: close');
            header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length());
            ob_end_flush();
            @ob_flush();
            flush();
        }
    }